# va_start / va_end + vsnprintf issue on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I use next function:

```
void CharTest(const char * format,...)
{
  char buffer[1024];
  va_list    args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, args);
  va_end(args);

  fnt->Render(0, 30, 0, buffer);

  for(int i=0; i<strlen(buffer); i++)
  {
    fnt->printf(0, 60 + i*30 , 0, "%d) - %d", i+1, (int)buffer[i]);
    fnt->printf(200, 60 + i*30 , 0, "%d) - %c", i+1, buffer[i]);
  }
}
```

Test example:

```
CharTest("Russian. Русский");
```

On Android 4.x it's works correctly, but on Android 5 I have problem with non-english characters.

Screenshots from devices:

[image]

Please, help me localize problem.

p.s. NDK, API level 10

**EDIT:**

**Dan Albert:** You right! Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using extended ASCII rather than UTF-8. IIRC the code backing the various printf functions is expecting UTF-8.